# ruby rails - getting a collection of objects from a collection of foreign keys

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Easy one i think/hope... I have a query that returns a list of 20 unique foreign keys:

```
@results   = Report.select("distinct user_id").where("datetime_utc >= ? AND datetime_utc <= ?",@utc_time_slot , @utc_time_slot_end).order("score DESC, quality DESC").limit(20)
```

this returns an array (ActiveRecord::Relation class):

```
[#<Report user_id: 803>, #<Report user_id: 809>, #<Report user_id: 806>, #<Report user_id: 801>, #<Report user_id: 830>, #<Report user_id: 860>, #<Report user_id: 858>, #<Report user_id: 856>, #<Report user_id: 854>, #<Report user_id: 852>, #<Report user_id: 851>, #<Report user_id: 850>, #<Report user_id: 849>, #<Report user_id: 846>, #<Report user_id: 859>, #<Report user_id: 866>, #<Report user_id: 2022>, #<Report user_id: 863>, #<Report user_id: 862>, #<Report user_id: 838>]
```

What do i need to do with this @results array to extract the collection of users form the users table that the user_id list refers to (in the same order)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for preserving order. First - eager load users in original query. In this case

```
users = @results.map(&:user)
```

Second - reorder on ruby side

```
idx = User.find(@results.map(&:user_id)).index_by(&:id)
users = @result.map{|r| idx[r.use_id]}
```

Comment: yep - both of these work - the second solution is slightly faster it seems. thanks

Comment: If you eager load properly first one should be faster

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
users = @results.collect(&:user)
```

Comment: Without eager load on original query it will result in N queries

Comment: users = @results.includes(:user).collect(&:user)

Answer (score 0):

Hej,
First of all you need to prepare the array of user_ids. it should look like this [209, 902, ..., 890] (you can use map or collect method to do that) then just build sql query like that:

```
User.where(:id=>user_ids)
```

where the user_ids is prepared array

Comment: That won't preserve the ordering though.

Comment: hi there - the problem with that is that the order of the original array is lost  (it rearranges the results based on user id...)

Comment: tou can inlude users objects to your query... http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: using includes - will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

`User.find(@results.map(&:user_id))`

Comment: hi there. thanks for this: i've had a quick try and it returns an error - so i converted @results.to_a and then it returns no results.

Comment: @user1051849 Weird. I'm pretty sure this should work. since I often use this technique. Looking into it.

Comment: @user1051849 Yep. Should work. No idea why it isn't doing so for you. What kind of error did you get on the fist try?

Comment: @user1051849 Aha.. Since we're working with arrays here, I would have presumed that the ordering would stick.